# Elegant way to create a nxn boundary mask for convolution in python

Tags: python, numpy

Whats the most pythonic way of writing a function that returns a nxn boundary mask for convolotion, e.g for 3x3 it will return `[[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]`, for 5x5 it will return `[[1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]` and so on.

this works (but isnt so pythonic):

```
def boundaryMask(size):
    mask=np.zeros((size,size))
    for i in range(size):
        mask[0][i]=1
        mask[i][0]=1
        mask[i][size-1]=1
        mask[size-1][i]=1
    return mask
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to create an array of *ones*, and then assign zeros to the center of the array using slicing:

```
N = 4
x = np.ones((N, N))
x[1:-1, 1:-1] = 0
x
#array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Put in a function and test on various sizes:

```
def boundaryMask(size):
    mask=np.ones((size,size))
    mask[1:-1,1:-1] = 0
    return mask

boundaryMask(1)
# array([[ 1.]])

boundaryMask(2)
#array([[ 1.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  1.]])

boundaryMask(3)
#array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  0.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])

boundaryMask(4)
#array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```